# How to use glGenerateMipmapEXT on windows when my graphic driver support it?

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

This is my situation:
1) I have checked with the the **glewinfo** tool of the GLEW library and found that my graphic driver support the glGenerateMipmapEXT function:

```
glGenerateMipmapEXT:                                         OK
```

2) I have get the GLEW code and rebuild it on VC++ 2010, I dont know whether files in the `auto\core\` or `auto\extensions\` folder affect my build or not :(

3) When building my source code which use the `glGenerateMipmapEXT` function, the VC++ give me an error

```
 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGenerateMipmapEXT
```

So, how do I use the `glGenerateMipmapEXT` function?

Comment: How are you using GLEW?  Via DLL or in-project?

Comment: I built the glew_share project in the glew source code and use glew via the `dll` file (of course, I have linked the `lib` file to my project, too) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- init opengl window
- glewInit()
- create the texture and use glGenerateMimapEXT()

  if (GLEW_EXT_framebuffer_object)
  {
      // you have FBO and glGenerateMipmapExt !
  }

you should have GFX card that supports OpenGL 2.1 to be sure to have those extensions...

Comment: I have the Intel HD graphic card with glGenerateMipmapEXT supported (as above), but I cannot build my project.